# Remove class for elements within a group for Isotope filtering

Tags: jquery, click, each, jquery-isotope

I'm attempting to remove the class 'is-checked' from all buttons in a group when a user clicks on the 'all' button. There are two groups of filter buttons I'm working with: categories and tags.

I've been able to create a function that removes the class 'is-checked' from all buttons across both groups, but I've not yet been able to isolate the function to each group, although I'm very close.

The final function will add the class 'is-checked' to the 'all' button and remove the class from any other buttons within that specific group. The function works, except for the problematic line below:

```
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
```

The code:

```
// class toggling for all buttons by group
    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        var $this = $(this);
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            if ( $this.hasClass('all') ) {
                $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                $this.addClass('is-checked');
            }
            else {
                $buttonGroup.find('.all').removeClass('is-checked');
            }
        });
    });
```

As the title mentions, this is for use within the Isotope framework for a portfolio with combination filtering (hence the two distinct groups of filters).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with scope. The variable `$buttongroup` lives in the function that `each` calls, and not in the event handler for click. I would recommend solving it like this:

```
// When someone clicks a button in a button group.
$('.button-group button').click(function() {
    // Get the button that was clicked.
    $this = $(this);
    // Get the button group the button that was clicked is in.
    $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    // And now this is just a copy of your old code below.
    if ( $this.hasClass('all') ) {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $this.addClass('is-checked');
    }
    else {
        $buttonGroup.find('.all').removeClass('is-checked');
    }
});
```

As you can see, the `each` is not needed with this approach. Instead, the button finds out what button group it is inside using [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: Wonderful! I had to make a slight alteration in order to have the 'is-checked' class attach to the all button (I had another piece of code doing a simple class toggle), but this worked pretty much out the box. My thanks indeed for such a quick and enlightening response :)

Comment: Roger! Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Anders, it took me a few minutes to wonder what you meant by "scroope", that you meant "scope".  I fixed it.